# how use microsoft Azure Speech Translation listen system voice，no listen Microphone，I work use C#

Tags: c#, azure, speech

I want use MicroSoft Azure support the Speech Recognition Translation api.
about this link:https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/services/cognitive-services/translator-speech-api/

it only use Microphone listen vocie,but this is not my hope. I want only listen system voice by itself.no vocie from Microphone listen Environmental noise

```
  // Translation from microphone.
    public static async Task TranslationWithMicrophoneAsync()
    {
        // <TranslationWithMicrophoneAsync>
        // Translation source language.
        // Replace with a language of your choice.
        string fromLanguage = "en-US";

        // Voice name of synthesis output.
        const string GermanVoice = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, Hedda)";

        // Creates an instance of a speech translation config with specified subscription key and service region.
        // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
        var config = SpeechTranslationConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");
        config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = fromLanguage;
        config.VoiceName = GermanVoice;

        // Translation target language(s).
        // Replace with language(s) of your choice.
        config.AddTargetLanguage("de");

        // Creates a translation recognizer using microphone as audio input.
        using (var recognizer = new TranslationRecognizer(config))
        {
            // Subscribes to events.
            recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING in '{fromLanguage}': Text={e.Result.Text}");
                foreach (var element in e.Result.Translations)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"    TRANSLATING into '{element.Key}': {element.Value}");
                }
            };

            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.TranslatedSpeech)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED in '{fromLanguage}': Text={e.Result.Text}");
                    foreach (var element in e.Result.Translations)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"    TRANSLATED into '{element.Key}': {element.Value}");
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"    Speech not translated.");
                }
                else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                }
            };

            recognizer.Synthesizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                var audio = e.Result.GetAudio();
                Console.WriteLine(audio.Length != 0
                    ? $"AudioSize: {audio.Length}"
                    : $"AudioSize: {audio.Length} (end of synthesis data)");

                if (audio.Length > 0)
                {
                    #if NET461
                    using (var m = new MemoryStream(audio))
                    {
                        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(m);
                        simpleSound.PlaySync();
                    }
                    #endif
                }
            };

            recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

                if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                }
            };

            recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSession started event.");
            };

            recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSession stopped event.");
            };

            // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
            Console.WriteLine("Say something...");
            await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop");
            } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

            // Stops continuous recognition.
            await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        // </TranslationWithMicrophoneAsync>
    }
```

Comment: How is it going to listen to "environmental noise" without a microphone?

Comment: I not need environmental noise ,and only listen system Voice. it like you want Record the screen ，environmental noise is a trouble

Comment: Hi @醉月问天, if you want to get the most out of StackOverflow you will need to explain better your issue, giving more details about what you did and how you did it, you can include code. Improving your grammar will help you a lot as well as it's hard to follow along. Always think that people that read your post is busy and lack the context you have, so make it easy and simple for the users to help you!

Comment: @mrbarletta thanks ,I just use overflow，Not familiar with operation.